# How to set cursor at given postion in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div

```
<div id="user_status" class="status expanddiv" onkeyup="username_Search('New','user_status');" contenteditable="true" data-text="What's on your mind?...">
 Some Text will goes Here.
</div>
```

when username_Search function call, its through cursor at 0 postion. while i need to stay cursor at its actual postion. i can get cursor postion before call this function. but not able to set.

Does ant one have solution for this?

Comment: Are you changing the content of the div in username_Search function?

Comment: Yes,, i am changing. i am converting text in to url links. like : google.com.. its becomes <a href="www.google.com">google.com</a>

After converting into link its through cursor at 0 position..

Comment: Is requirement to _set_ cursor position , or return current cursor position ? thanks

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: I want it for all browser...  but currently using chrome.

Comment: @user3337174 check the answer works for chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Chrome or Firefox then the below code will works well to accomplish the task. This code not tested in IE or Safari.

**The setCaretPosition function is what you want I think**

```js
function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
            var caretPos = 0, containerEl = null, sel, range;
            if (window.getSelection) {
                sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.rangeCount) {
                    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                    if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                        caretPos = range.endOffset;
                    }
                }
            } 
            return caretPos;
        }

function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos) {
            if (window.getSelection) {
                pos = (ctrl.textContent.length > pos ? pos : ctrl.textContent.length);
                var selection = window.getSelection();
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(ctrl.childNodes[0]);
                range.endOffset = pos;
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
                selection.collapse(ctrl.childNodes[0], pos);
            }
}

function username_Search(st,str)
{
   var ctl = document.getElementById('user_status');
var pos = getCaretPosition(ctl);
    document.getElementById("user_status").textContent 
= "dsdssadsadasdffstjdyjdrtyurtystseryds";
    setCaretPosition(ctl,pos);
}
```

```html
<div id="user_status" class="status expanddiv" onkeyup="username_Search('New','user_status');" contenteditable="true" data-text="What's on your mind?...">
 Some Text will goes Here.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, 
in function "setCaretPosition", its give me error on this line
     pos = (ctrl.textContent.length > pos ? pos : ctrl.textContent.length);

Error is - uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefine

Comment: i was making a silly mistake. Now its solve. Thank You.

Comment: If the problem solved, you can mark it as answer. :)